# How do I properly use the identifier property?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I want my program to be like this

```
if ([UIImageViewObject identifier]==@"heyItsMeYeaCoolDude")
{
    do some methods
}
```

Whenever I do this though my programs crashes saying:

> 2012-07-29 19:09:58.401 Bridges[2711:f803] -[UIImageView identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8874f70

With a bunch of crap after it.

In my storyboard, I typed `heyItsMeYeaCoolDude` under label in the identity inspector, and now my program is complaining.

I know I could use tags also, but I'm already using my images tag for something else, help!

Comment: Views do not use identifiers, only View Controllers.

Comment: ok well would it be ok to subclass uiimageview to get properties of it to track it down? i know its bad to subclass unbutton but what about uiimageview @ctrahey

Comment: Typically you would only be "tracking down" individual views inside view controllers, so the go-to method is to give your View Controller an "outlet" (or simply a @property, depending on how you set it up) which points to the view of interest.

Comment: @ctrahey If the OP is creating new views at runtime, this wouldn't work.  A subclass or something similar would be required.  Considering the sample code that's probably not what he's trying to achieve right now, but one could argue that more extensible code now might save time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the suggestion you made in the comment below your question, @ownageGuy, an answer to the question you pose:

You're welcome to subclass anything you like. Subclassing `UIImageView` is a perfectly acceptable solution to this problem.  You might also consider the container pattern; ie. create a class which contains an instance of a `UIImageView` and an `NSString` for the identifier. Then even if there did happen to be a detriment to subclassing `UIImageView`, as you fear, it would be eliminated.

```
@interface UIImageViewContainer : NSObject
{
    UIImageView* imgView;
    NSString* identifier;
}
```

Then you create an object of type `UIImageViewContainer`, set `imgView` to the appropriate `UIImageView`, and store the identifier string inside `identifier`.